# xquery recursion for counting/formatting characters in a string

Tags: xquery

I am trying to find a solution to the following problem in xquery 1.0. I need to use just recursive functions **alone**. The input will always have characters between A-Z only.

```
1. AAABBCCD --> A1A2A3-B1B2-C1C2-D1
2. ABBAB     --> A1-B1B2-A2-B3
```

Thanks. What I have tried so far does not lead anywhere.

Comment: Good question. Just for the record, there exists a single-XPath 2.0 solution -- non-recursive of course, as this is Xpath **2.0**. And certainly, this is also an XQuery 1.0  solution, as XQuery 1.0 is a superset of Xpath 2.0

Comment: Slkrasnodar, Was my answer useful for solving your problem? If you have any questions/problems with it, please state them in comments. If everything is OK, please consider accepting an answer.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev, thanks for the answer. I am still going through the first answer by Leo and porting it to oracle env. FYI, I did upvote both answers. Please allow me some time so that if I have questions I can come back.

Comment: Slkrasnodar, No problem. Happy New Year

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you probably want to split the string up into individual characters, this can be done in multiple ways (e.g. using `fn:substring(...)`), I will use `fn:string-to-codepoints($str)`:

```
declare function local:to-chars($str) {
  for $cp in fn:string-to-codepoints($str)
  return fn:codepoints-to-string($cp)
};
```

**Example:** `local:to-chars('ABC')` yields the sequence `('A', 'B', 'C')`.

For your formatting scheme, you have to keep track of

1. how often you encountered each character until that point for the numbering, and
2. what the previous character was (for the dashes).

I will track the counts per character in an XQuery 3.0 [map](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#maps-and-arrays) and keep the previous character in a separate argument of the recursive function. All there is to do now is to

- go through each character one-by-one,
- get and update its count in the map,
- decide if a dash should be added before it in the output string,
- and recurse.

We are finished when all characters have been processed.

```
declare function local:format($chars, $counts, $last, $out) {
  if(empty($chars)) then $out
  else (
    let $c          := head($chars),              (: current char :)
        $new-chars  := tail($chars),              (: rest of the chars :)
        $count      := ($counts($c), 1)[1],       (: old count if present, `1` otherwise :)
        $cc         := $c || $count,              (: char with count :)
        $new-out    := if($c eq $last) then $out || $cc  (: updated output string :)
                       else $out || '-' || $cc,
        $new-counts := map:put($counts, $c, $count + 1)  (: updated map :)
    return local:format($new-chars, $new-counts, $c, $new-out)
  )
};
```

We call it with an empty map and the first character in the sequence as "previous" character to avoid a dash at the start of the output.

```
declare function local:format-string($str) {
  let $chars := local:to-chars($str)
  return local:format($chars, map{}, head($chars), '')
};
```

This works with arbitrary characters: `local:format-string('HELLO')` yields `'H1-E1-L1L2-O1'`.

**EDIT:**

I must have skipped over the *XQuery 1.0* part, I blame lack of caffeine... You can also keep the counts as a sequence of 26 integers instead of a map:

```
declare function local:format($chars, $counts, $last, $out) {
  if(empty($chars)) then $out
  else (
    let $c          := $chars[1],
        $new-chars  := subsequence($chars, 2),
        $pos        := string-to-codepoints($c) - 64,
        $count      := $counts[$pos],
        $cc         := $c || $count,
        $new-out    := if($c eq $last) then concat($out, $cc)
                       else concat($out, '-', $cc),
        $new-counts :=
          (
            subsequence($counts, 1, $pos - 1),
            $count + 1,
            subsequence($counts, $pos + 1)
          )
    return local:format($new-chars, $new-counts, $c, $new-out)
  )
};

declare function local:format-string($str) {
  let $chars := local:to-chars($str),
      $counts := for $i in 1 to 26 return 1
  return local:format($chars, $counts, head($chars), '')
};
```

Comment: Nice conversion of the XQuery 3.0, map based solution to some XQuery 1.0 way using a simple sequence. But `head` and `tail` were not in XQuery 1 I think, so you need to throw in some more `subsequence` or predicates. And use `concat` instead of `||`.

Comment: Leo and @MartinHonnen , Just for the record, there exists a single-XPath 2.0 expression / solution -- non-recursive of course, as this is Xpath **2.0**

Comment: Thanks Martin, I hope it's proper XQ1.0 now.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My task is to learn recursion in xquery and find out how the variables are *managed* between recursive calls. Your post showed me those parts of problem solving in xquery. I wasn't bothered with the minor issues of head/tail/pipe.

Comment: @LeoWörteler, Does this work only with the 26 characters in the Latin alphabet, or not? Maybe a more general solution would be more useful for the readers?

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to see how to achieve the following in xquery 1.0. I am
>   looking for a solution using the recursive functions **alone**. The
>   input will always have characters between A-Z only.

**Here is a single XPath 2.0 expression**:

```
 string-join(
             (for $s in .,
               $indS in 1 to string-length($s),
               $cp in string-to-codepoints($s)[$indS]
                return
                  (
                  '-'[$indS gt 1 and $cp ne string-to-codepoints($s)[$indS -1]]
                    ,
                    concat(codepoints-to-string($cp),
                            for $i in 1 to count(index-of(string-to-codepoints($s), $cp))
                             return
                               $i[index-of(string-to-codepoints($s), $cp)[$i] eq $indS]
                           )
                    )
                ),
              ''
             )
```

**This, of course, is non-recursive, which I think is an advantage -- we are guaranteed that no call-stack overflow will happen :)**

->>>>>  *Also note, that  the input characters may have any value* -- not only [A-Z]. <<<<<-

**This solution works even if the input string has many hundreds of distinct / different characters and is many thousands of characters long.** Compare this to a naïve recursive algorithm that, on every new character read from the input string  allocates a new sequence of hundreds of numbers...

---

**XSLT 2.0 - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="t">
    <xsl:sequence select=
     "string-join(
                 (for $s in .,
                   $indS in 1 to string-length($s),
                   $cp in string-to-codepoints($s)[$indS]
                    return
                      (
                      '-'[$indS gt 1 and $cp ne string-to-codepoints($s)[$indS -1]]
                        ,
                        concat(codepoints-to-string($cp),
                                for $i in 1 to count(index-of(string-to-codepoints($s), $cp))
                                 return
                                   $i[index-of(string-to-codepoints($s), $cp)[$i] eq $indS]
                               )
                        )
                    ),
                  ''
                 )
       "/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The above transformation simply evaluates the XPath expression against every `<t>` element of the source XML document.

**When applied on this XML document**:

```
<z>
    <t>AAABBCCD</t>
    <t>ABBAB</t>
    <t>aBcBaBcc</t>
</z>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
A1A2A3-B1B2-C1C2-D1
A1-B1B2-A2-B3
a1-B1-c1-B2-a2-B3-c2c3
```

Comment: Learned a few things. As you said, yours is probably more efficient, but I may have influenced Leo with my title and the wording of the problem to post his reply. So, I have chosen that as my accepted answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Slkrasnodar, Glad this answer helped. Regardless of which answer you accepted, I would strongly recommend using the non-recursive solution for real-world production work in order to avoid unexpected crashes.

Comment: At least in *BaseX*, both problems (call stack and a new sequence per recursive call) are not really relevant. Since the function is *tail recursive* the call stack does not grow arbitrarily. This is a well-known optimization that most XQuery processors should implement. Sequences are represented internally as *Finger Trees* (a variant of a B-Tree), which means that inserting a value in the middle results in a sequence that shares most of its structure with the original one. A good implementation of a functional language should not discourage recursive algorithms.

Comment: Great comment, @LeoWörteler, Yes, not all XQuery processors are created equal. And thanks for implementing the Finger Tree data structure in BaseX! I have seen a statement from an authoritative person that the W3C working groups didn't mandate tail-recursion optimization because they didn't know how to strictly define "tail recursion" ...